# Office 2016/365 VBA fails to update PPT links from old script

Tags: vba, office365, powerpoint

I have a need to change lists of links in large PPT presentations.  I had working code that did it fine.  Recently I upgraded to Office 2016 and now the script is not working correctly.

I simple put my old and new path strings in a 2 dimensional array and loop through them correcting the links in the PPT.

This has some debug code in it, and come commented lines where I was trying things to fix it, please ignore.

```
For j = 0 To UBound(MyArray)

  oldString = MyArray(j, 0)
  newString = MyArray(j, 1)

  If Len(oldString) > 1 Then
    For Each pptSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
      For Each pptShape In pptSlide.Shapes
        If (pptShape.Type = msoLinkedOLEObject) Or (pptShape.Type = msoChart) Then
'           With pptShape.LinkFormat

                If InStr(1, (pptShape.LinkFormat.SourceFullName), (oldString), 1) Then

                ' debug points
                q = pptShape.Id
                r = pptShape.Name
                s = pptSlide.SlideIndex
                t = pptSlide.SlideNumber

                ' The actual source link
                x = pptShape.LinkFormat.SourceFullName
                ' substitute source link with new string
                y = Replace(x, oldString, newString)
                ' Further adjust new link so any spaces in tab names have %20
                y = Replace(y, "%20", " ")
                'y = Replace(y, " ", "%20")
                'y = Replace(y, "file:///", "")


                ' ignore errors when can't see new link
                On Error Resume Next

                pptShape.LinkFormat.SourceFullName = y
                DoEvents
                ' debug assignment
                w = pptShape.LinkFormat.SourceFullName

                   Debug.Print "old string " & oldString
                   Debug.Print "replacement string " & newString
                   Debug.Print "org link x " & x
                   Debug.Print "new link y " & y
                   Debug.Print "result   w " & w
                   Debug.Print "---"
                   Debug.Print ""


                End If

'            End With
        End If
      DoEvents
      Next pptShape
    DoEvents
    Next pptSlide

  End If

Next
```

PPT 2016 has changed the links to look like HTML, with a preceeding file:/// and changed all spaces to "%20"

Here's a couple of examples running my script.  Now, if I have a different path and a different filename, it's requiring 2 passes of the code with different "matching" strings (one with and one without %20) in each pass.  If the filename is the same, then it will do it in one pass of the code, but it opens the files 4 times per link.  As I have hundreds of links that's extremely time consuming.

Also in office 2015, as long as I had the target open, no reopening happened.  Now, if I have the target open, I get an error saying it can't open 2 files by the same name.

**Example 1** with diff paths and diff filenames, all flies closed.

Array fed to code with links to be changed:

> ```
> MyArray(0, 0) = "file:///\\aFolder\bFolder\Reports\daily%20report%20generator.xlsm!Site%20Completions!R2C2:R17C17"
> MyArray(0, 1) = "file:///\\aFolder\bFolder\Reports\Rpt-Other\daily%20report%20generator2.xlsm!Site%20Completions!R2C2:R17C17"
> ```

Orig link reported in debugger:

> ```
> file:///\\aFolder\bFolder\Reports\daily%20report%20generator.xlsm!Site%20Completions!R2C2:R17C17
> ```

1st pass, opens files twice (assume target and source), results in the link missing the %20's but no path or filename changed:

> ```
> \\aFolder\bFolder\Reports\daily report generator.xlsm!Site Completions!R2C2:R17C17
> ```

Change the array's 1st element (source path) and run the code a 2nd time.  This time the match string is the same except w/o %20.  Again, it opened 2 files in this pass, this time it changed the path and filename:

> ```
> \\aFolder\bFolder\Reports\Rpt-Other\daily report generator2.xlsm!Site Completions!R2C2:R17C17
> ```

**2nd example**, filenames are the same, only path changes.  Neither file open.  There is only one link to update.

Original link:

> ```
> file:///\\aFolder\bFolder\Reports\daily%20report%20generator.xlsm!Site%20Completions!R2C2:R17C17
> ```

pass 1 opens a file 4 times, but does not take 2 runs of the script as it did in example 1, results in:

> ```
> \\aFolder\bFolder\Reports\Rpt-Other\daily report generator.xlsm!Site Completions!R2C2:R17C17
> ```

Not a big deal but worth noting maybe: If I save file, links don't change, but if I Save, close reopen, PPT adds file:/// and %20's back to the original links.

It appears the HTMLizing of the filenames has hosed the way it's working. And it's causing the files to be opened 4 times per link.  Apparently twice per source and target.

Worst of all in the 1st example, which changes both the filename and the path, I have to run the scrip twice, changing the source/match string from with to without "%20" to get it to succeed.

Anyone know how to fix this?

1/26/17: Edited some for better formatting and clarity.

Comment: What do you mean by *"it opens the files 4 times per link"*? *it* the macro? files the ppt files?

Comment: I mean for the single link in the file, when I run that code, as soon as it hits the line that changes the sourcefullname, I see it open an excel file 4 times.  I have a bandwidth monitor running and I can see it there, each download (the source and target files are on a network share), and in excel which is open with an unrelated file, I get 4 popup dialogs that say "downloading file..."  As the number of links to change goes up, the file opens go up accordingly.  Edit:  Each set of file open's is associated with a single iteration of the innermost loop and happen when that line is executed

Comment: Note there is a single link in my test file.  The real file has hundreds.

Comment: So basically you're looking for a way to change those hyperlinks in offline mode.

Comment: re offline mode, I don't know.  I'm online, network fully on, so I don't understand why it would be offline.  Maybe I misundrstood what you meant.  I just want to change the links (path and or filename) with a script and I don't want it to have to download a file 4 times for every link in the PPT.  Which is what it's doing now.  Office 2016 seems to have killed it.

Comment: Right now, even if the PPT is linked to say 3 charts in a particular single  excel file, the script above will cause a file to be downloaded a total of 12 times, 4 times for each link/chart.  I presume those 4 times (have no simple way I see to verify) is it downloading the source and the target files 2 times each (net 4).

Comment: Edited original post for better formatting and clarity.